# Windows Template Studio Caliburn.Micro Add New Page

Tags: uwp, caliburn.micro, navigationview

I'm trying to develop an UWP solution with Windows Template Studio, Caliburn.Micro and Navigation View. The thing is that when I add a new page I get a "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" error while trying to navigate go it.

I noticed that in the method:

```
private void OnItemInvoked(WinUI.NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IsSettingsInvoked)
        {
            // Navigate to the settings page - implement as appropriate if needed
        }
        else if (args.InvokedItemContainer is WinUI.NavigationViewItem selectedItem)
        {
            var pageType = selectedItem.GetValue(NavHelper.NavigateToProperty) as Type;
            var viewModelType = ViewModelLocator.LocateTypeForViewType(pageType, false);
            _navigationService.NavigateToViewModel(viewModelType);
        }
    }
```

ViewModelLocator.LocateTypeForViewType(pageType, false) is returning "NULL".

I added the new View and ViewModel in their respective folders and called them TestPage and TestViewModel. I also already added "_container.PerRequest();" in the App.xaml.cs file and the Shell_Test entry in the Resources.resw file.

This is what the ShellView.xaml looks like:

```
<winui:NavigationView
    x:Name="navigationView"
    IsBackButtonVisible="Visible"
    IsBackEnabled="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsBackEnabled, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected, Mode=OneWay}"
    IsSettingsVisible="False"
    cm:Message.Attach="[Event ItemInvoked] = [Action OnItemInvoked($eventArgs)]"
    Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush}">
    <winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
       
        <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_ContenedorMapa" Icon="Document" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:ContenedorMapaPage" />
        <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Page1" Icon="Document" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:RNDPage" />
        <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Page2" Icon="Document" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:IPHPage" />
        <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Page3" Icon="Document" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:SIPPage" />
        <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Test" Icon="Document" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:PruebaPage" />
    </winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior
            x:Name="navigationViewHeaderBehavior"
            DefaultHeader="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected.Content, Mode=OneWay}">
            <behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior.DefaultHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock
                            Text="{Binding}"
                            Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                            Margin="{StaticResource SmallLeftRightMargin}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior.DefaultHeaderTemplate>
        </behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="shellFrame" DataContext="{x:Null}" />
    </Grid>
</winui:NavigationView>
```

Can anyone tell me what is it that I'm missing? I've been searching for a while now with no luck for a tutorial or any kind of information with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Has your issue been solved? Do you have any progress?

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT Nope... It wasn't solved. As soon as I find a solution, I'll post it here.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Caliburn Micro follows a [naming convention](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/naming-conventions#:%7E:text=Naming%20Conventions%20for%20Name%20of%20a%20Type&text=%E2%80%9CViewModel%E2%80%9D%20is%20simply%20added%20to,name%20of%20its%20companion%20ViewModel) for Views and ViewModels (ending in View/ViewModel pr Page/PageViewModel) by default.The 'LocateTypeForViewType' method, would follow the rules of naming convention to find/detect the ViewModel for specified Views.

In your case, the naming convention is different (TestPage/TestViewModel). You have two options here

- Change the naming of your View/ViewModels to follow the convention used by Caliburn Micro

Rename your View/ViewModels to **TestPage/TestPageViewModel**

- Use NameTransformer to identify your own naming convension

The naming conventions are based on rules. Caliburn Micro allows you to add your own rules

For example.

```
ViewLocator.NameTransformer.AddRule("Model$", string.Empty);
```

You can read more on the Name Transformer here.
https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/name-transformer

Comment: Thanks for the reply! sadly it didn't work. In UWP (at least when you generate the project using Windows Template Studio) the naming convention is already set to Page/ViewModel. Is there anything else I could try? Thanks a lot!!